# Can Glue Workflow or Trigger get parameters from EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge, aws-glue-workflow

### My system design

- I have created 4 Glue Jobs: testgluejob1, testgluejob2, testgluejob3 and common-glue-job.
- EventBridge rule detects SUCCEEDED state of glue jobs such as testgluejob1, testgluejob2, testgluejob3.
- After getting Glue Job's SUCCEEDED notification, Glue Trigger run to start common-glue-job.
  [image]

### Problem

- I want to use the jobname string in common-glue-job script as parameter
- Is it possible to pass parameters to Glue Workflow or Trigger from EventBridge?
  [image]

### The things I tried

- Trigger can pass parameters to common-glue-job
  　 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-trigger.html

```
       Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
       ...
         Actions:
           - JobName: prod-job2
             Arguments:
               '--job-bookmark-option': job-bookmark-enable
```

- If set Run Properties for Glue Workflow, I cat get it from common-glue-job by using boto3 and `get_workflow_run_properties()` function. But I have no idea how to put Run Properties from EventBridge by CFn
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflow-run-properties-code.html
- I set Target InputTransformer of EventBridge Rule, but I'm not sure how to use this value in common-glue-job.

```
DependsOn:
- EventBridgeGlueExecutionRole
- GlueWorkflowTest01
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
Name: EventRuleTest01
EventPattern:
  source:
    - aws.glue
  detail-type:
    - Glue Job State Change
  detail:
    jobName:
     - !Ref GlueJobTest01
    state:
     - SUCCEEDED
Targets:
  -
    Arn: !Sub arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:workflow/${GlueWorkflowTest01}
    Id: GlueJobTriggersWorkflow
    RoleArn: !GetAtt 'EventBridgeGlueExecutionRole.Arn'
    InputTransformer:
      InputTemplate: >-
        {
          "--ORIGINAL_JOB": <jobName>
        }
      InputPathsMap: 
        jobName : "$.detail.jobName"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you already have information in EventBridge event, but cannot access it from your Glue job. I used the following workaround to do this:

1. You need to get an event ID from Glue workflow properties

```
import sys
import boto3
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
event_client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['WORKFLOW_NAME', 'WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])
event_id = glue_client.get_workflow_run_properties(Name=args['WORKFLOW_NAME'],
                       RunId=args['WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])['RunProperties']['aws:eventIds'][1:-1]
```

2. Get all NotifyEvent events for the last several minutes. It's up to you to decide how much time can pass between the workflow start and  your job start.

```
response = event_client.lookup_events(LookupAttributes=[{'AttributeKey': 'EventName',
                                                         'AttributeValue': 'NotifyEvent'}],
                                                         StartTime=(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)),
                                                         EndTime=datetime.datetime.now())['Events']
```

3. Check which event has an enclosed event with the event ID we get from Glue workflow.

```
for i in range(len(response)):
      event_payload = json.loads(response[i]['CloudTrailEvent'])['requestParameters']['eventPayload']
      if event_payload['eventId'] == event_id:
                event = json.loads(event_payload['eventBody'])
```

In event variable you get full content of the event that triggered workflow.

Comment: Which class instance is `self` in this case?

Comment: @wtfzambo, I created a class to separate data processing logic and technical details such as getting event from EventBridge. I will update the answer to get rid of `self`.

Comment: hey @ChildishGirl thanks a lot. I'm gonna need this relatively soon so I needed to understand the context. 

Just to understand the context better, cloudtrail needs to be enabled to get the EventBridge event details? Is it possible to get them directly from EventBridge, without using cloudtrail? Thanks again :)

Comment: You don't need to enable CloudTrail, it is enabled by default. I didn't find the way to get event details from EventBridge event that triggers Glue Workflow. To provide you more context on how I used this approach: link to my [Glue job](https://github.com/ChildishGirl/glue-data-pipeline/blob/main/cdk-assets/assets/glue_job.py) and you can find full infrastructure where it works in the same repository. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have one more question: What's the need for `[1:-1]` to get the event id? In my tests, the array is already 1 element only.

Comment: @wtfzambo, it was some time ago when I tested it, but if I remember correctly, it was related to the type of output: I got string with brackets, such as "[some_id]". So I resolved brackets to get only event ID.

Comment: yup you're right, I confirm that's still the case